# PDF of product of two complex Gaussian random variables?

Tags: probability-distributions, normal-distribution, density-function

I am trying to find the PDF of product of two i.i.d complex Gaussian random variables say $X\sim \mathcal{C}{N}(0,\sigma^2_x)$ and $Y\sim \mathcal{C}{N}(0,\sigma^2_y)$ but not getting it exactly.

Any help in this regard will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried to get the pdf for the product of real Gaussians?

Comment: Yes .... I had obtained that ...also direct formula is available in "Probability Distributions Involving Gaussian Random Variables: A Handbook for Engineers and Scientists". Also in case of real Gaussian the PDF expression is simple while that is not the case with complex Gaussian ...so I am facing the issue...